# Make IntoIterator trait implementation lifetime-dynamic

Tags: rust, iterator, lifetime

I have this code which works:

```
impl<T> IntoIterator for Range<T>
where
    T: Display + PartialOrd + 'static,
    RangeInclusive<T>: Iterator<Item = T> + DoubleEndedIterator,
    Rev<RangeInclusive<T>>: Iterator<Item = T>,
{
    type Item = T;
    type IntoIter = Box<dyn Iterator<Item = T>>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        if self.start > self.end {
            Box::new((self.start..=self.end).rev())
        } else {
            Box::new(self.start..=self.end)
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to refactor it to use a dynamic lifetime instead of `'static`.
However, I cannot figure out how to do this, since I always seem to run into the *unconstrained lifetime parameter* error:

```
impl<'a, T> IntoIterator for Range<T>
where
    T: Display + PartialOrd + 'a,
    RangeInclusive<T>: Iterator<Item = T> + DoubleEndedIterator,
    Rev<RangeInclusive<T>>: Iterator<Item = T>,
{
    type Item = T;
    type IntoIter = Box<dyn Iterator<Item = T> + 'a>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        if self.start > self.end {
            Box::new((self.start..=self.end).rev())
        } else {
            Box::new(self.start..=self.end)
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible, do use a dynamic lifetime here?

**Orther types**

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug, PartialEq)]
pub struct Range<T>
where
    T: Display + PartialEq,
{
    start: T,
    end: T,
}

impl<T> Range<T>
where
    T: Display + PartialEq,
{
    pub fn new(start: T, end: T) -> Self {
        Self { start, end }
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
error[E0207]: the lifetime parameter `'a` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
  --> src/lib.rs:56:6
   |
56 | impl<'a, T> IntoIterator for Range<T>
   |      ^^ unconstrained lifetime parameter
```

Comment: Please provide definitions for all types used in your question, as part of a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also include the entire error you see.

Comment: Are `Range`, `RangeInclusive`, `Rev`, etc all the standard library types, or your own?

Comment: Standard library.

Comment: Are you working on the standard library? Implementing that trait isn't allowed from an external crate: `error[E0117]: only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for types defined`

Comment: Sorry Range is a custom type as defined above. RangeInclusive and Rev are stdlib.

Comment: I think this is related: [E0207 Error example 4](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/error_codes/E0207.html#error-example-4) "Please note that unconstrained lifetime parameters are not supported if they are being used by an associated type."

Comment: Probably, yes. This is why my naive attempt failed. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Nitpick: The `Rev` constraint is redundant.

Comment: You can use `Either` instead of dynamic dispatch.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Thanks. That solved my issue. Also got rid of the superfluous trait bound. https://github.com/conqp/ranges/blob/main/src/lib.rs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Either` from [`either`](https://docs.rs/either/latest/either/enum.Either.html) or [`itertools`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/enum.Either.html) instead of `Box<dyn Iterator>` to hold one of two iterators, without the lifetime problems caused by `dyn Iterator`:

```rust
impl<T> IntoIterator for Range<T>
where
    T: Display + PartialOrd + 'static,
    RangeInclusive<T>: Iterator<Item = T> + DoubleEndedIterator,
{
    type Item = T;
    type IntoIter = Either<Rev<RangeInclusive<T>>, RangeInclusive<T>>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        if self.start > self.end {
            Either::Left((self.start..=self.end).rev())
        } else {
            Either::Right(self.start..=self.end)
        }
    }
}
```